# Подключение к SOAP (запрос строкой)

Tags: java, java-ee, soap

Здравствуйте.

Пытаюсь написать простейший клиент на Java подключения к вебсервису SOAP.

Проверил вариант с SOAP SAAJ. 
Работает, НО не устраивает тем, что необходимо под каждый SOAP запрос составлять свою объектную модель SOAP.

Существуют ли другие аналогичные варианты формирования SOAP request, полностью идентичные типу SOAP SAAJ.

Попробовал это заменить

```
        MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
        SOAPMessage soapMessage = messageFactory.createMessage();
        SOAPPart soapPart = soapMessage.getSOAPPart();

        String serverURI = "http://ws.cdyne.com/";

        // SOAP Envelope
        SOAPEnvelope envelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();
        envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("example", serverURI);

        /*
        Constructed SOAP Request Message:
        
            
            
                
                    mutantninja@gmail.com
                    123
                
            
        
         */

        // SOAP Body
        SOAPBody soapBody = envelope.getBody();
        SOAPElement soapBodyElem = soapBody.addChildElement("VerifyEmail", "example");
        SOAPElement soapBodyElem1 = soapBodyElem.addChildElement("email", "example");
        soapBodyElem1.addTextNode("mutantninja@gmail.com");
        SOAPElement soapBodyElem2 = soapBodyElem.addChildElement("LicenseKey", "example");
        soapBodyElem2.addTextNode("123");

        MimeHeaders headers = soapMessage.getMimeHeaders();
```

заменить на

```
MessageFactory msgFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();

        String reqEnv = "<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:example=\"http://ws.cdyne.com/\"><SOAP-ENV:Header/><SOAP-ENV:Body><example:VerifyEmail><example:email>mutantninja@gmail.com</example:email><example:LicenseKey>123</example:LicenseKey></example:VerifyEmail></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>";
        SOAPMessage soapMessage = msgFactory.createMessage(null, new ByteArrayInputStream(reqEnv.getBytes()));
```

и

```
    SOAPMessage message = MessageFactory.newInstance().createMessage();
    SOAPPart soapPart = message.getSOAPPart();
    soapPart.setContent(new StreamSource(new FileInputStream("c:\\musor\\1.xml")));
```

при том, что результирующий SOAP request везде одинаковый получаю в оставшихся 2-х случаях ошибку

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Body>
<soap:Fault>
<faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode>
<faultstring>Server did not recognize the value of HTTP Header SOAPAction: .</faultstring>
<detail />
</soap:Fault>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

НО работает только объектный первый способ на SAAJ.

Существуют ли способы другие аналогичные? если да то какие.

Заранее благодарю за ответ.

Answer (score 0):

В общем, нашел решение.

```html
   public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

        String addr = "http://ws.cdyne.com/emailverify/Emailvernotestemail.asmx";
        String request = "<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:example=\"http://ws.cdyne.com/\"><SOAP-ENV:Header/><SOAP-ENV:Body>\n" +
                "<example:VerifyEmail><example:email>mutantninja@gmail.com</example:email>\n" +
                "<example:LicenseKey>123</example:LicenseKey></example:VerifyEmail>\n" +
                "</SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>";

        URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(addr);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        try {
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(request.length()));
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml;charset=UTF-8");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        connection.setRequestProperty("SoapAction", "http://ws.cdyne.com/VerifyEmail");
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        PrintWriter pw = null;
        try {
            pw = new PrintWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
        } catch (IOException e2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
        pw.write(request);
        pw.flush();

        try {
            connection.connect();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        BufferedReader rd = null;
        try {
            rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    connection.getInputStream()));
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        String line;
        String respond = "";
        try {
            respond = rd.readLine();
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null)
                respond = line;

        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(respond);
    }
```